# X-ray: Aluminium mass absorption co-efficient vs photon energy

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, x-rays

I am doing this experiment on X-rays and I have to do this part of measuring aluminium mass absorption coefficient vs photon's energy. I have done all the work but now stuck in the last step (step 4). Below is the task (6.5) and the curves I have obtained.

[image]

[image]

I did the same measurement with Carbon as well,

[image]

Can somebody please help me with step 4? As in how should I compare the slope of the curves with equation 5? I don't know what value of photon energy to be used in either cases of aluminium and carbon. Please, help!

Link to Kaye and Laby: http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_2/4_2_2.html
http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_2/4_2_2a.html

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\sigma = k \,E^{- 3}_\gamma$ where $k$ is a constant.

Take logs of both sides.

$$\ln\sigma = \ln(k \,E^{- 3}_\gamma)=-3\ln E_\gamma + \ln k$$ and compare with the general equation of a straight line $y=mx+c$